# Goal: scraping URLs, Error Message: No implicit conversion of String into Integer

Tags: ruby

I'm learning my first coding language (Ruby) and I'm having trouble crawling a link.  I'm trying to grab image-URLs and eventually going to save to a CSV.  I've looked at many tutorials and a lot of question on here, but none seem to solve my problem.

The problem appears to be in the final line (Line 19).

Error Message: 19:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Any help would be appreciated!

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

PAGE_URL = "http://www.bestbuy.com/site/samsung-showcase-27-8-cu-ft-french-door-refrigerator-with-thru-the-door-ice-and-water-stainless-steel/5236091.p?id=1219116001631&skuId=5236091"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))

link_extract = page.css('div#pdp-content div.image-gallery-main-slide a img[data-index="1"]')

puts link_extract[0]['src']
```

Comment: Can you post what `link_extract` is coming in as?

Comment: Hey Sid, do you mean the result I get from running this code?  If so, here is a screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/NFo4NUQT3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a large part of this page is built with javascript.
If you look at the raw html you get you won't see the content you're looking for since youre essentially doing a curl to get the data.

Soo how should you proceed? I'd say you have two options:

1. The easiest way to get the data you want, is to get the json they're using at `#pdp-model-data`
2. Use some kind of web driver that works well with javascript. I tried phantomjs but it looks like that page contains some invalid syntax and it's only pulling the first image.

e.g.

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

url = "http://www.bestbuy.com/site/samsung-showcase-27-8-cu-ft-french-door-refrigerator-with-thru-the-door-ice-and-water-stainless-steel/5236091.p?id=1219116001631&skuId=5236091"

session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)
session.visit(url)

page = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(session.html)(session.html)
page.search("#pdp-content div.image-gallery-main-slide a img")
# => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ffe438d4100 name="img" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ffe438d409c name="src" value="http://pisces.bbystatic.com/image2/BestBuy_US/images/products/5236/5236091_sa.jpg;canvasHeight=500;canvasWidth=500">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ffe438d4088 name="alt" value="Samsung - Showcase 27.8 Cu. Ft. French Door Refrigerator with Thru-the-Door Ice and Water - Stainless-Steel - Larger Front">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ffe438d4074 name="width" value="500">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ffe438d4060 name="height" value="500">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ffe438d404c name="data-index" value="0">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ffe438d4038 name="style" value="display: block; ">]>]
```

edit #1:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'json'

url = "http://www.bestbuy.com/site/samsung-showcase-27-8-cu-ft-french-door-refrigerator-with-thru-the-door-ice-and-water-stainless-steel/5236091.p?id=1219116001631&skuId=5236091"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))
json = page.css('#pdp-model-data').attribute('data-gallery-images').value
gallery = JSON.parse(json, symbolize_names: true)

puts gallery[1][:url]
#=> "http://img.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5236/5236091cv1a.jpg"
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I'm currently having trouble installing the poltergeist gem, but I'm interested in what you mean by "get the json they're using"  (I'm very new to coding).  I found the link I would need inside #pdp-model-data (http://pisces.bbystatic.com/BestBuy_US/images/products/5236/5236091cv1a.jpg) under "Alternate View 1", but could you expand on what you mean by "get the json they're using"?  I'm going to google what I can in the mean time, but any help is appreciated!

Comment: I know this isn't correct/complete yet, but is this closer to what I need:

`page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))
<br>
link_extract = page.css('div#pdp-model-data data-gallery-images')
<br>
puts link_extract`

Also, does the ".css" need to be changed to ".json" or something?

Comment: @NickJ987 To explain a little more. It looks like the image gallery is built using javascript and some json thats on the page. So instead of trying to get the markup of image you could just look at the json thats used to build the html. I've included a working example in my edit #1.

Comment: Perfect.  This answers my question.  So to summarize: The HTML I was trying to get was **not actually on the initial page**; it was loaded from the json when the user scrolled down to that area of the page, thus it could not be read by Nokogiri (Which parses the initial HTML?).  So the json hash within the array had to be parsed, and then it 'puts' the second url?  I just want to make sure I understand this before moving on.

Comment: Exactly. The alternative (#2), used phantomjs to run the webpage in a headless browser, this way the sites javascript is loaded and evaluated, thus generating the image gallery.